# Auto Populate Gravity Forms with data from a prior CPT Submission

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I have a gravity PayPal form that collects info on local businesses. I also have a custom post type. When a visitor fills out and submits the form, A custom post type submission is pre-populated from the form submission and set to pending. That's all working. Client now want's a renew form that will pre-populate with the data from their custom post submission (preferred), or their original form submission. These Businesses are NOT logged in or WP users. All of the information they enter is not sensitive and most or all of it will display on the site.

I'm thinking  when a person comes up to renew I can show a form that has 1 field - organization name. I can use that form to get the entry ID from the meta key value and then use the entry ID to pre populate the renew form.

Is it possible?  I'm new to gravity forms and in the documentation I'm finding hooks and filters that possibly might make it work, but no examples that apply to this particular problem and know idea of the best way to proceed. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hardest:** Gravity Forms supports [dynamic population](https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/#hooks) which allows you to fetch data and populate it into the form in a number of ways.

**Harder:** I [wrote a snippet](https://gist.github.com/spivurno/32e914d67723f89717be2904ce6234c4) that accepts an entry ID as a query parameter and use the dynamic population methods above to  populate the associated entry into the form.

**Easiest:** Check out [Gravity Forms Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) if you don't want to both touching code. It can handle populating pretty much any kind of data into your form and has a powerful UI for filtering which data should be populated (including data from previous entries and custom post types).

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Does the example require Gravity Wiz to be installed?

Comment: Are you referring to the harder example? If so, that is a plug-n-play snippet that only requires Gravity Forms.

Comment: OK thanks, it's been a crazy week so I haven't had a chance to test, but it looks like it could be what I need.

Comment: David, so with Populate Anything would it be possible to dynamically populate a form  with a CPT  entry  by matching a (unique) text field and then on submission update the existing CPT entry?

Comment: Yes, Populate Anything supports populating data from entries and posts (including CPTs). As for updating the post, you would need to use this filter to set the populated post ID for updating on submission.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_post_data/

Comment: David, thanks I'm going to push that the client purchase.